# Show "show more" dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have created a forum-like page where all messages are as follows (simplified):

```
<div class="message-wrapper" *ngFor="let node of allNodes">
      <div [class]="isExpanded(node.id) ? 'message-content expanded' : 'message-content'">
           <div class="content" [innerHtml]="node.comment"></div>
           <span (click)="toggleExpand(node.id)" class="showMore">{{ isExpanded(node.id) ? 'Show less' : 'Show more' }}</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.message-content {
     overflow-y: hidden;

     .content {
        line-height: 1.5vh;
        max-height: 6vh;
        overflow-y: hidden;
     }
 }

.message-content.expanded {
    max-height: 10000000vh;
    overflow: visible !important;

    .content {
         overflow: visible;  
         max-height: 100000000vh;
    }
}
```

And when clicking the 'Show more' and 'Show less' span, the `div.content` expands as expected.

The problem I'm currently encountering is that I want to show the 'Show more' only when the text is actually overflowing.

I know I can find this out by subtracting the `scrollHeight` and `innerHeight` but for this to work, I need to have the correct (unique) `nativeElement` of the corresponding `div.comment` in my controller.

So my question:

How can I show the 'Show more' span, when the `div.content` is overflowing while all Messages on the page have the same classes etc.?

The thing that makes this question unique from existing questions is that I don't have a single element but I have multiple of the same elements (multiple messages) thus needing the unique node element.

Comment: Maybe you can add the `overflowing` property to each node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a workaround where I'd add a dynamic id to all divs and spans. Then I loop through all nodes and check if the text is overflowing. If it is I set `hidden=false` to the label.

```
for(let comment of this.allComments) {
   //element which contains the comment content
   let content = document.getElementById('div'+comment.id);

   // if the element height is bigger than the displayed height (with an error margin of 10)
   if(content.scrollHeight - content.clientHeight > 10) {
       // the corresponding 'show more' label
       let label = document.getElementById('label'+comment.id);
       label.hidden = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: How would you check whether the text is overflowing?